recursion with setTimeout flow anomaly
Please see the below code.
I thought the '11111111' line would never be executed but it is.
Can anyone please explain.


function outer() {
  function inner(dur) {
    console.log('in inner');

    setTimeout(() => {

      outer();
      console.log('11111111');

    }, dur);

  }
  console.log('in outer');
  inner(5000);
}

outer();



I expected an infinite loop. That happened.
But I never expected the '11111111' to execute.

Why should it never be printed? You call the outer, you call the inner, and setTimeout gets executed, after 5000ms the callback passed to setTimet get called. Thats exactly how it should work.

Remember that setTimeout() is asynchronous, it doesn't wait for the callback function to complete. So outer() returns immediately and then console.log('11111111') is executed before the timeout.

So this isn't really recursion, because timeout functions are executed from the event loop's toplevel, not during the execution of the function that calls setTimeout().

@Barmar, your last comment is what I was after. Could you please elaborate on it. My confusion stemmed from the fact that from the above code if I comment out the setTimeout(), then the console.log('11111111') line doesn't execute and we have a true recursion.  ```
function outer() {
function inner(dur) {
console.log('in inner');
outer();

console.log('11111111');

}
console.log('in outer');
inner(5000);
}
outer();

setTimeout() is an asynchronous function. It schedules its callback function to be called later, then returns immediately without waiting for it. So anything after setTimeout() will be executed immediately, without waiting for the timeout.
So inner() returns immediately after it's called, and then outer() returns immediately. Sometime later (after dur milliseconds), the callback function is invoked. This isn't really recursive, because outer() and inner() have already returned. It's a new top-level call from the event loop.
In the callback, we execute outer() again. As above, it calls inner() again, which calls setTimeout() and returns, and then it also returns. Then console.log('11111111') is executed. dur milliseconds later this all will be repeated.
